# Check Struts presence runtime

Tags: java, struts, runtime

Which is the quickest way to check the presence of Struts runtime from a Java class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Peter mentioned you can try to load `org.apache.struts.action.RequestProcessor` using `Class.forName("org.apache.struts.action.RequestProcessor")` if it throws `ClassNotFoundException` then Struts is not present.

Answer (score 0):

Try loading or using a class you need. If its not there, it will throw a `ClassNotFoundException` or `NoClassDefFoundError` respectively.